# Postman: custom signing request with SHA256 and RSA

Tags: javascript, python, postman, sign

I wrote an interface to make requests to the internal audible api with python. Every API request needs to be signed with RSA SHA256.

Now I want to test the endpoints of the API with Postman and make use of the pre request script function. But I'm not firm with javascript. Maybe someone can help me in translate the following python function to a Postman script:

```py
def sign_request(
    request: httpx.Request, adp_token: str, private_key: str
) -> httpx.Request:
    """
    Helper function who creates a signed requests for authentication.

    :param request: The request to be signed
    :param adp_token: the token is obtained after register as device
    :param private_key: the rsa key obtained after register as device
    :returns: The signed request
    """
    method = request.method
    path = request.url.path
    query = request.url.query
    body = request.content.decode("utf-8")
    date = datetime.utcnow().isoformat("T") + "Z"

    if query:
        path += f"?{query}"

    data = f"{method}\n{path}\n{date}\n{body}\n{adp_token}"

    key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(private_key.encode())
    cipher = rsa.pkcs1.sign(data.encode(), key, "SHA-256")
    signed_encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher)

    signed_header = {
        "x-adp-token": adp_token,
        "x-adp-alg": "SHA256withRSA:1.0",
        "x-adp-signature": f"{signed_encoded.decode()}:{date}"
    }
    request.headers.update(signed_header)

    return request
```

I found out how to get the request method and the body. I can get the path and query with `pm.request.url.getPathWithQuery()`. To add the headers to the request I use `pm.request.headers.add`.

But I doesn't know how to get the datetime in isoformat, join strings and sign the data.

Comment: This should help you - https://blog.kiprosh.com/sign-api-request-using-postman-pre-request-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem to make this in Postman is that you can use only those packages available in [sandbox](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-external-libraries). So for this, you have [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) as the unique package helper for crypto operations.

```js
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var moment = require("moment");

signRequest(pm.request, "yourAdpToken", "yourPrivateKey")

function signRequest(request, adpToken, privateKey) {
    const method = request.method;
    const path = request.url.getPathWithQuery();
    const body = request.body.raw;
    const date = moment.utc().format();
    const data = `${method}\n${path}\n${date}\n${body}\n${adpToken}`
    const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(data, privateKey);
    const signedEncoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

    pm.request.headers.add({
        key: 'x-adp-token',
        value: adpToken
    });

    pm.request.headers.add({
        key: 'x-adp-alg',
        value: 'SHA256withRSA:1.0'
    });

    pm.request.headers.add({
        key: 'x-adp-signature',
        value: `${CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(signedEncoded)}:${date}`
    });
}
```

Adding the above to the Pre-request Script will add your wanted headers to the request like this:
[image: Postman request body]

You may need to change the encode parts, check the [encode options](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps a lot. But you use HS256 for signing. But the request needs to be signed with RS256. I have read a lot about crypto-js but found nothing about support rsa.

Comment: I found a [Postman lib](https://joolfe.github.io/postman-util-lib/) who supports RS256. But I can't figure out how to use this to sign my `data` string.I can load my key with `keyObj = pmlib.rs.KEYUTIL.getKey(privateKey)` but if I try to sign with `keyObj.sign(data, "SHA256")` I ran into an "Error: " without any further informations

Comment: Try to change you getKey method by `KEYUTIL.getKeyFromCSRPEM()` or `KEYUTIL.getKeyFromPlainPrivatePKCS8PEM()`. Also note that in the [examples](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.crypto.Signature.html#sign) they are creating a sign object first and then calling to the `init()` (assign the key) method before update the string and call the `sign()` method

Answer (score 5):

I'm get it running with the [pm lib](https://joolfe.github.io/postman-util-lib/). Thank you for your help.

The only issue is getting the private cert, who contains newlines, from env var gives an error with these code `sig.init(privateKey);`. I had to write the private cert string directly in the pre request script.

Here are my script.

```js
eval( pm.globals.get('pmlib_code') );
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var moment = require("moment");

const adpToken = pm.environment.get("adp-token")
// private-key loaded from env var doesn't work because of newlines in it; bugfix
const privateKey = pm.environment.get("private-key")
// use private-key in pre request script directly make use of newline correctly
const privateKey2 = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE...==\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"


signRequest(pm.request, adpToken, privateKey);

function signRequest(request, adpToken, privateKey2) {
    const method = request.method;
    const path = request.url.getPathWithQuery();
    const body = request.body || "";
    const date = moment.utc().format();
    const data = `${method}\n${path}\n${date}\n${body}\n${adpToken}`;
    var sig = new pmlib.rs.KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA256withRSA"});
    sig.init(privateKey);
    var hash = sig.signString(data);
    const signedEncoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash));

    pm.request.headers.add({
        key: 'x-adp-token',
        value: adpToken
    });

    pm.request.headers.add({
        key: 'x-adp-alg',
        value: 'SHA256withRSA:1.0'
    });

    pm.request.headers.add({
        key: 'x-adp-signature',
        value: `${signedEncoded}:${date}`
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

Now reading the device cert from env var works. I had to replace `const privateKey = pm.environment.get("private-key")` with `const privateKey = pm.environment.get("private-key").replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`